# I cant get my scene to render in its entirety it only shows a png image from the scenes files

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine

When ever I try to render out the scene It seems to render out the png sequence rather then the scene in its entirety.
The first image is the scene I'm, currently trying to render
Second one is the result

[image]
And the rendered result[image]

Comment: Is there anything in the VSE?

Comment: provide more screenshots and more explanation or even better: provide your blend file

Comment: as Hiserod suggests, there's probably something in the VSE, in that case in the Output panel > Output > Post ¨Processing you need to disable the Sequencer option

Comment: Thanks you guys so much!! It I had an mp4 file in the VSE, after removing it I was able to render without issue!!